# Как сделать переход между страницами без перезагрузки?

Tags: jquery

Например есть 2 страницы, и они ссылаются друг на друга. Как сделать переход между ними без перезагрузки?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос слегка некорректен.

Ответ [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

> Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал бы так:

```
<?php include"header.php";?>
<script>
function redir(url){
     $("#content").empty();
     $("#content").load(url);
}
</script>`
<div id="content"></div>
<?php include"footer.php";?>
```